There was x There is
In the two sentences below, is the use of "there was" (past tense) and "there is" (present tense) correct? Or should "there was" be used in both cases?
Let's face it: we all knew that there was no chance he could win the battle against that terrible disease.
Let's face it: we all know that there is no chance that he could win the battle against that terrible disease.

You should bold one more part of your examples:
#1

Let's face it. We all knew that there was no chance he could win the battle against that terrible disease.

#2

Let's face it. We all know that there was no chance he could win the battle against that terrible disease.

#3

Let's face it. We all know that there is no chance he can win the battle against that terrible disease.

Remember that could is the past tense of can. So you have to use the past tense there was in #2 because you're using the past tense he could.
You can use the present tense there is if you use the present tense he can, as in #3.
When you use the past tense in the second part of the sentence (there was no chance he could), the first part of the sentence refers to when you knew that there was no chance he could win. So because it happened in the past, if you knew it in the past, then you know it in the present, so you can use either:

We all knew that there was no chance...
We all know that there was no chance...

There's really no difference in meaning. One just puts an emphasis presumably on how long you've known the information.
There's probably a much more technical and grammatical way of explaining the rules.

Surely #3 (OP's second example) implies that the patient is still alive, #1 that he has died of his illness.

#3 is not OP's second example. I switched it to the present tense. I don't think OP's second example is correct.  I think it needs to be either "there was no chance" or "there is no chance he could have won". Am I wrong?

Oops, sorry.  Yes, your #3 implies he is still alive, and OP's second doesn't quite work.
